# Cbind/Rbind With Ifelse Condition

Tags: r, if-statement, cbind

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
x <- c("Yes","No","No","Yes","Maybe")
y <- t(1:10)
z <- t(11:20)

rbind.data.frame(ifelse(x == "Yes",y,z))
```

This produces

```
    X1L X12L X13L X4L X15L
1   1   12   13   4   15
```

The desired outcome is:

```
x
1   Yes   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
2    No   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
3    No   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
4   Yes   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
5 Maybe   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
```

I was thinking that I could use an ifelse statement with the rbind.data.frame() or cbind.data.frame() function. So if `x == "Yes"` then that would be combined with a vector "y". As shown in the first row of the desired output. Inversely if `x!="Yes"` then it would be combinded with the vector "z". How would I go about doing this. I also thought maybe indexing with the which() function could be possible but I could not think of how I would use it.

**UPDATE ANOTHER QUESTION**

Here is the code I am working with :

```
    a <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
    b <- 1:7 

    t(sapply(a, function(test) if(test==0) b else 0))

Which produces 

        [,1] [,2]      [,3] [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]     
    [1,] 0    Integer,7 0    Integer,7 Integer,7 Integer,7 Integer,7
```

Can any of you explain this? The code  below works but I was wondering why the sapply function does not work. Also how would I save the matrix that is created below?

```
`row.names<-`(t(t(rbind(b,0))[,(a!='1')+1L]),x)
```

**Answer To My Most Recent Question**

For the sapply function to work it needs the input in the else statement to be a vector so,

```
        a <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0)
        b <- 1:7 
        c <- rep(0, times = length(a))
        t(sapply(a, function(test) if(test==0) b else c))
```

Now this produces the proper output.

Comment: You should stick to one question per post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 t(sapply(x, function(x) if(x=='Yes') y else z))
```

Or

```
 `row.names<-`(t(t(rbind(y,z))[,(x!='Yes')+1L]),x)
```