# If Else Sequencing Condition

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

So I have asked a similar question before involving vectors and tried to just apply it a matrix as shown in [Cbind/Rbind With Ifelse Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542285/cbind-rbind-with-ifelse-condition).

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
y <- c(0,5,10,0)
n <- 9

R <- t(c(2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.95, 2.95, 2.95))
R <- (replicate(4,R))
R <- (matrix(R, nrow=4))
R <- t(apply(R,1,sort))

mat <- t(sapply(y, function(test) pmax(seq(test, (test-n+1), -1), 0) ))
mat



P <- replicate(ncol(R),(c(6447.88,6447.88,6447.88,5000)))

EnvTest <- new.env()
EnvTest$Orig <- c(548453.5,548453.5,548453.5,500000)


FuncTest2 <- function(pp) {
  EnvTest$Orig <- ifelse(R[,pp]==0|mat[,pp]!=0,EnvTest$Orig,EnvTest$Orig-(P[,pp]-EnvTest$Orig*R[,pp]/1200));
  return(EnvTest$Orig);
};
Test2 <- rbind(EnvTest$Orig,do.call(rbind,lapply(1:9,FuncTest2)));
x2 <- t(Test2);
x2;
```

The above code works perfectly fine, this is what I am having trouble with.

```
x2 <- t(sapply(y, function(x) if(x == 0) x2[,seq(1,10,2)] else x2[,seq(2,10,2)]))
```

which produces...

```
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]    [,11]    [,12]
[1,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 500000.0 537422.2 548453.5 548453.5 491701.3 526574.8 548453.5 548453.5 483577.3
[2,] 542942.6 548453.5 548453.5 495854.2 531892.4 548453.5 548453.5 487541.2 521245.9 548453.5 548453.5 479604.9
[3,] 542942.6 548453.5 548453.5 495854.2 531892.4 548453.5 548453.5 487541.2 521245.9 548453.5 548453.5 479604.9
[4,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 500000.0 537422.2 548453.5 548453.5 491701.3 526574.8 548453.5 548453.5 483577.3
        [,13]    [,14]    [,15]    [,16]    [,17]    [,18]    [,19]    [,20]
[1,] 515905.7 543171.1 548453.5 475624.0 505533.7 532933.3 548453.5 467953.1
[2,] 510726.1 538058.5 548453.5 471793.3 500328.6 527795.6 548453.5 464103.5
[3,] 510726.1 538058.5 548453.5 471793.3 500328.6 527795.6 548453.5 464103.5
[4,] 515905.7 543171.1 548453.5 475624.0 505533.7 532933.3 548453.5 467953.1
```

which is too long because the desired output is a 4 x 5 matrix, and this has 4 times the number of columns. In the question that I asked before which is similar was dealing with vectors which is why I think my code does not work. 
The desired output is:

```
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
    [1,] 548453.5 537422.2 526574.8 515905.7 505533.7
    [2,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 538058.5 527795.6
    [3,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5
    [4,] 500000.0 491701.3 483577.3 475624.0 467953.1
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

I am starting to think maybe the way to do this is change some of the code when the variable "Test2" is created. Not exactly sure how to change, but it is an idea.

Comment: @akrun sorry about that edited it. Yeah I thought I had it figured out... I didn't

Comment: @akrun tried doing it with indexing and rbind, which produces the right numbers but the wrong order of the rows.

Comment: I think your condition is not correct.  Based on the expected output, you are selecting 1,3,5,7 and 9 columns.

Comment: @akrun I don't think that is true. Based on the condition that I created everything is jumbled up.

Comment: You have 4 values in y i.e. 0, 5, 10, 0. and you are looping it with `sapply` with an if else condition. i.e. if the value is 0, you are getting the 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 columns of x2, and if not, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.  So, this is repeated 4 times as we loop through the y values.

Comment: @akrun expect columns 1,3,5,7,9 does not contain the value 500000.0

Comment: But in your expected output, the last row 1st column is 500000.  I think something is really missing in the details.

Comment: @akrun maybe I just did not get your original comment about the sapply function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84621/discussion-between-adam-warner-and-akrun).